# Scrolltop not going to the correct position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to focus the top of a div on an anchor click using the below code.

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#" + divid).offset().top}, 100);
```

However, it is not getting scrolled to the top of div , rather the focus goes to a position inside the div. I cross checked the `offset().top` value of the div with the top value in Page Ruler chrome addon and they are in sync.So ideally it should scroll to the top of div. Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Comment: Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/7qgjjr47/

Comment: Try removing top and bottom margin and padding from the `div` and see if that helps.

Comment: The div does not have a top or bottom margin. Also the offset.top() value is correct. But for some reason , the focus goes inside the div, as if the scrollTop has been assigned a value greater than offset.top()

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle seems to be working (except that you forgot `preventDefault()` in the click handler).

Generally, you need to account for border, padding, margin on the scroll container (the window in your case). For a generic solution, have a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hashchange/c368ce9c642c1a70edda).